# java ThreadPoolExecutor can't create a native thread

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I need to have a global thread pool in my system to process client's orders. The system is based on tomcat and should accept client's requests 24/7. I used ThreadPoolExecutor like this:

```
 private ThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ThreadPoolExecutor(100, 1000, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue());
```

But sometimes my system hang out with exception: 'OutOfMemory: Cannot create a new native thread'. So the questions are: 
1. Will all submitted threads reside in the pool forever till it shutdown?
2. What should I use to create a thread pool which may reuse or clean completed tasks, so it will never hang?

I also added a log message before pool.submit:

```
logger.info("Active count: "+pool.getActiveCount()+" completed: "+pool.getCompletedTaskCount());
```

But active count is always zero. Why? The java version is openJDK 8 on FreeBSD

Comment: 1) did you read the docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor%28int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue%29 (only the core will) ? Maybe a fixed size pool? Really depends. Do you need that many threads? Has your system 1000 cores and can actually do 1000 things in parallel?

Comment: @zapl if the tasks are IO-Bound then it makes sense to have a pool of size greater than the number of cores

Comment: @SleimanJneidi A thousand threads is a lot.  Even a hundred threads is a lot.  No matter what hardware the service is going to run on, there will be practical limits to how many simultaneous clients and how many requests per second it can handle.  The trick is, to design a system that will degrade gracefully under pressure instead of simply crashing on an OOM error.

Comment: @jameslarge there are a lot of people out there who can afford machines with 100s of cores and tera-bytes of memory, maybe the OP is one of them :)

Comment: @SleimanJneidi, OK, maybe a thousand threads is not _always_ a lot, but the OP's system apparently _is_ running out of threads.  Even the biggest servers will run out of something if you push them hard enough, and the trick still is to gracefully degrade performance without crossing the line instead of crossing it and crashing.  An appropriately configured thread pool is one of the tools that you can use to achieve that goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too many things might go wrong, the obvious ones are:

1. `maximumPoolSize` is set to 1000, this is a magic number and not related to the hardware the program is running on.
2. `Back-pressure`, you using `LinkedBlockingQueue` which welcomes any new task, you might need to consider using `ArrayBlockingQueue` and give it a `capacity`.

configuring the `maximumPoolSize` depends on your application, are your tasks `compute bound`? Then having a pool size more than the number of cores available on the production machine (not the dev machine) wouldn't gain you anything rather then paying for the overhead of context-switching and memory consuming.

There is a very useful method in Java that gets you the number of cores you have, please use it.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

Comment: Thank you, but should core size be equals to processors count, or just be N*processorsNumber? So, if I have 4 processors, may I specify my core size as 16, 32, or just 4? Thanks

Comment: @avalon again it depends on the tasks, compute bound tasks are very different from IO-bound tasks.

Comment: The tasks are dealing with rabbitMQ+different computations+groovy

Comment: My current issue is seems that threads are stuck in TPE, like the are still alive, but getActiveCount is always 0.

Comment: @avalon I believe that groovy is language and not a task

Comment: Yes,sorry, I just tried to explain. The tasks are mixed - IO+computations.

Comment: @avalon have a look at this http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-Thread-Pool-Performance-Tuning